# Why need to add escape character for $? in eval?

Tags: bash, eval

I have next:

```
$ export A=1
$ eval "echo $A; echo $A; lll; echo $?"
```

The output is:

```
1
1
-bash: lll: command not found
0
```

I don't know why I cannot get the exit code of `lll`, and I happen to try next:

```
$ export A=1
$ eval "echo $A; echo $A; lll; echo \$?"
1
1
-bash: lll: command not found
127
```

You can see above works, meanwhile next also work:

```
$ export A=1
$ eval "echo \$A; echo \$A; lll; echo \$?"
1
1
-bash: lll: command not found
127
```

I wonder, why I had to add one `\` before `$?`? Also, why `\` before `$A` is not a must?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that, because you have embraced the whole expression to be evaluated, in double quotes. This means that all parameters inside it will be expanded, before `eval` is invoked. If you don't escape `$?`, the parameters to be expanded are `A` and `?`. You get the value of `A` before `eval` is run (which is what you want), but you would also get the value of `?` **before** `eval` is run (which is not what you want). The backslash causes a literal `$` to be passed to `eval`, hence defering the time of calculating the status code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ eval "echo $A; echo $A; lll; echo $?"
```

The variables enclosed in double quotes are expanded. The line above is the same as:

```
$ eval "echo 1; echo 1; lll; echo 0"
```

In fact, this string is exactly what `eval` receives as argument. You don't even need to `export A` for this.

In order to achieve what you want to should enclose the string in single quotes. This way the variables are not expanded any more and `eval` receives as argument the string exactly as you typed it.

---

Try these two sets of commands

```
$ export A=1
$ B="echo $A; echo $A; lll; echo $?"
$ eval $B
$ A=2
$ eval $B
```

vs.

```
$ export A=1
$ B='echo $A; echo $A; lll; echo $?'
$ eval $B
$ A=2
$ eval $B
```

That's a difference, isn't it?